# MySql Matemathic Operator

Tags: mysql

let says i have data like this.

```
name    price each    quantity   subtotal  
Apple   15000         2          ?
```

How to get the (?) in MySQL?
which on mathematics the calculation is like this
subtotal = price each * quantity

Comment: So that `subtotal` field is in fact not in your data at all?

Comment: @tomala: yes the subtotal is not on my data, it processed from the query result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT name, price, quantity, price*quantity AS subtotal
    FROM YourTable
```

Comment: it really surprise me, i really didn't realize if we can do mathematics operator like that in MySQL same as PHP. Anyway thank you very much. This is really enlighten me.